# Translating primitives in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glut, freeglut

I want move several squares by a specified distance in different directions. To begin with I used `glTranslatef(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f);` where `0.4f` is the square's side length, but it seems to have stopped working when I switched machines. I have also tried `glVertex3f(-0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f);` but without success. I initialized vertices:

```
float vertices[] = {
    -0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f,
    -0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
    0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
    0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f,
};
```

I initialized buffers in `main()`:

```
unsigned int VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// Colors
unsigned int VBO2;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

Then I went on to draw the shapes:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4);
glTranslatef(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 1, 4);
glTranslatef(-0.4f, -0.4f, 0.0f);
```

So how to move these primitives along X and Y axis respectively?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what your code does: `glTranslate` is only available when using the fixed function pipeline. And it only affects draw commands after the translate command (you code looks as if you have the translate after draw). Then, `glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 1, 4);` reads out of bounds because you tell it to start at the second vertex and read 4 vertices (meaning index 1,2,3,4), but you only have data for 4 vertices.

Comment: Also: There is no guarantee that location 1 is for colors. In the fixed-function pipeline, only location 0 is specified for being the positions, everything else is up to the implementation and might work on one vendor/card/driver version and not on others.

Comment: Yeah @BDL, I wanted to draw one square in default position and move others, that's why I draw, translate and then draw once more. I also tried replacing `GL_POLYGON` with `GL_QUADS` but with no visible effect